# How to use Plotly to save/extract data information selected in a graph

Tags: python, plotly

I used plotly to create a scatter plot from a csv.

It is possible to select a point or multiple points in this graph and save/extract information related to this point contained in the csv ?

Comment: You don't provide much information to go on, but I suggest reading this link: https://plotly.com/python/click-events/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I can expand on this: I plotted using a csv file. Now the original csv is overwritten but I have the old graph. Now, I want to compare the values in both - for which I have to "restore" the old csv from its plot. Since plotly uses some form dictionary for plotting, can we get back the original csv file from it?

Comment: In continuation with my previous comment, I see that if I save the image as html page, then the data is available as part of the "Plotly.newPlot()" argument list. Trying to see how this can be got from svg.